# how to convert a 1x1 mat that contains a 161x161 struct to a numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy, matrix, scipy, np

I've been trying to convert a .mat file to a numpy array forever, I've now realized that it's not working because my .mat file is a 1x1 matrix that that holds. a 161x161 struct within the first row, first column. it looks like this:

[image]

[image]

would anyone have any advice on how to go about converting this to a numpy array?

I've been trying to use load mat from the scipy library but it hasn't been working

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are showing..  In the previous question you showed python code.  what's this (1,1) object?  Is a numpy array with object dtype.  The table stuff looks like a `csc` sparse matrix.  There is documented `scipy.sparse` package for this.

Comment: I think a `print(data_mat)` (as loaded in the previous question will better help set the stage.  `data_mat['FCM']`, should be the variable.  What's its `shape` and `dtype`?  `data_mat['FCM'][0,0]['Matrix']` might be a `csc` sparse matrix.